# How to cache the results from a WCF service call

Tags: wcf, caching

I have a WCF service which is called in 4 different places in my system. It returns approx 500 records from the database each time it's called.

I would like to use a cache in place of making the call to WCF every time because data in the DB will remain unchanged.

Is there anything built into WCF for this or do I have to create my own solution?

Answer (score 2):

There are several classes in .NET to allow you to cache objects in memory and there are also open source solutions which will do this for you.

If you wish to code this yourself one class you can use is [MemoryCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache(v=vs.110).aspx)

An open source solution can be found here: [Redis.IO](http://redis.io/)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Jon's answer, you can also use [SQL Cache Dependency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443(v=vs.110).aspx).

> If your **WCF** Web HTTP service depends on data stored in a SQL database,
>   you may want to cache the service's response and invalidate the cached
>   response when data in the SQL database table changes.